# scanf() function doesnt work program in c [GNU/LINUX]

Tags: c

Today i have been coding a came across with this code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPj1a.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    char letra1;
    char letra2;

    printf("Primera letra: ");
    scanf("%c", &letra1);
    printf("Segunda letra: ");
    scanf("%c", &letra2);

}
```

When I execute the code the first `scanf()` executes well but the second even didn't execute and close the program and I don't know why.

[Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm4CN.png)

```
> ej3
Primera letra: A
Segunda letra:
```

Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Post your code, input, output and expected output here.  Without that, your post is unclear.

Comment: Add the code to your question. There's no need to upload an image for that since SO supports code posting and formatting as part of your question.

Comment: `"%c"` --> ``" %c"``

Comment: It's jut that the second scanf doesnt execute and just printf() and close the program

Comment: How do you know that the first scanf() call "executes well" if you don't print anything out afterwards? edit: didn't see that execution screenshot. Whoops

Comment: The problem is solved with the " %c".

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score. But please do post the actual code for your program: cut from your editor, paste into the question body, select the code and type Alt-K to indent it.

Comment: Don't post your code as an image.

Comment: The `scanf()` function is a brute to foist on novice programmers.  See [Beginners Guide Aware from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) for some discussion.  Don't be upset that you find it hard to use — it is hard to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `scanf` format string `" %c"` to skip any pending whitespace characters, including the newline the user typed after the first letter. As posted, the second `scanf()` reads the `\n` that is pending in the input stream, so it does not wait for user input.